# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using path

Tags: python

I installed anaconda and python on Windows 10 without errors. I tried to run an example from scrapy startproject fundrazr I got the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\bld\scrapy_1572360424769\_h_env\python.exe"  "C:\Users\demo\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe" startproject fundrazr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
python -m scrapy startproject project name.
```

Now I am also curious about why the previous instruction was wrong.